# MODX: How to insert links to other resources in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, modx, modx-revolution

Am I missing something? When inserting links to other resources, it seems like there should be a "resource picker" that auto inserts the `[[~id]]` tag for internal links. Is such a "picker" available from the TinyMCE editor in MODX Revolution?

I mean *I* don't mind using the resource syntax, but I don't see my users being comfortable having to learn and remember it.

When I click on the "Insert/edit link" button, this is the dialog I get:

[image]

Clicking on the "Browse" button to the right of "Link Url" gives me the following dialog:

[image]

I don't see anything that allows me to pick a resource.

I'm using MODX Revolution 2.2.1-pl (traditional) on IIS 7.5. There could be a possible issue there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, I was definitely missing something. The "Insert/edit link" dialog has a search box which auto completes as you type the name of existing documents into it. Selecting a document from there inserts the document's ID with the proper syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There should be.

When editing text if you highlight a word to be used as a link and then click on the Edit/Insert link icon (a chain link) there is a "Link List" select box that contains all your resources selecting one will populate the link url with the [[~id]] of the selected resource.

Comment: I added some screenshots to my question. I'm not seeing the "Link List" anywhere though :( What version are you running and what platform?

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice Revolution I was checking on Evo.

Comment: No problem, I got it figured out. Plus 1 for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In the MODX Revo manager better use the ACE-Editor (Extras/Package/download extras choose Ace) for buiding up your template.
Now you may drag a Ressource from the Ressource-Tree on the left and drop it into your code in the Ace-Window.
[image: drag&drop an Ressource]
This is the easiest way to create a Ressource-Link.